# Numeric answer for systems of equations with more variables than equations

Tags: python, math, sympy, equation-solving

Ok so first I want to say, it doesn't have to be done with `sympy`, if there's an easier way to do it please let me know, but below was my failed attempt:

I'm trying to use `sympy` to approximate a solution under a loose condition. I have over *10* variables which i call `x0, x1, x2...`
and I have 2 constraints for them, which I call `eq1` and `eq2`. I have some constants which I name as `c0, c1, c2...`

so `eq1` and `eq2` looks approximately like this:

```
eq1 = c0 + c1 / (c2 * x0 + c3 * x1 + ...)
eq2 = c20 + c21 * x0 / (c21 * x0 + c22 * x1 + ...)
```

In the above, all the `x0, x1...` are *positive*, `c0` and `c20` are *negative*, and the other `c`s are *non-negative*.

I think its pretty obvious that I have way too many variables and not a lot of constraints so I should have a bunch of solutions, and I only really want the first one that the machine can find. But when I use this:

```
s = sympy.nsolve((eq1,eq2),(x0,x1,x2,...),(a bunch of guesses on x#))
```

then error pops out and says I need at least as many equations as variables (`NotImplementedError: need at least as many equations as variables`), so I added some other eqs:

```
eq3 = 0
eq4 = 0
...
```

and I did this:

```
s = sympy.nsolve((eq1,eq2,eq3...),(x0,x1,x2...),(a bunch of guesses on x#))
```

and another error pops out saying: `ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular`

At this point I'm lost, seems like I can't get it work. Please help on giving any method to solve this system of equations, thanks so much!

P.S. I know there are some other questions like this, but I specifically want my program to be able to just guess for variables with random numbers (ideally as close to 0 as possible) and **produce one acceptable set of numbers as solution** when the system is under-determined with free variables. I can't seem to find an answer for this.

Comment: You should be setting the VARIABLES to fixed values (X3 = 0, X4 = 0 ...) NOT the EQUATIONS (eq3 = 0 eq4 = 0 ...).

Comment: @lastchance thanks but I don't want the extra variables to be 0 coz I want to find a solution where ideally none of them are 0. i.e. I want ANY solution that fits, but not a solution that I pre-define any of the variables to anything to cut down the free variables. This is for future generalization in the future cases some constants may turn to 0, reducing the free variables amount case-by-case

Comment: sympy does have some solving capabilities but it's mostly intended for symbolic calculations. If you are only interested in numeric calculations then numpy or scipy are a much better choice.

Comment: For instance I suggest taking a look at [numpy.linalg.solve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) and [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)

Comment: Note that the equation `0 == c0 + c1 / (c2 * x0 + c3 * x1 + ...)` seems "hard" because of the variables in the denominator, but actually it is equivalent to `c0 * (c2 * x0 + c3 * x1 + ...) == -c1`, which is a linear equation.

Comment: Perhaps you can show us exactly what the equations are. If they can be rearranged to linear form then you could just reduce to row-echelon form or use the Simplex algorithm.

Comment: SymPy's symbolic solvers like `solve`, `linsolve` etc can handle underdetermined systems but `nsolve` is not intended for this purpose. You will likely get better answers if you show the equations (with runnable code) rather than summarising them.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I managed to fix the code, the linear equation idea was awesome! I got to a dead end and didn't realize :)